# Read entire configure command in Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, configure

When I run `brew install` to install a package via Homebrew, if the `configure` script is wider than my terminal, I can't read the entire thing. For example, this command is pasted verbatim from my terminal, I can't read the end of it.

```
==> Installing nginx-full from homebrew/nginx
==> Downloading https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/kevin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/nginx-full-1.10.1.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx-full/1.10.1 --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-ipv6 --sbin-path=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx-full/1.10.1/bin/nginx --with-cc-opt=-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.39/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0
==> make install
==> Caveats
```

Is there a way to make Homebrew wrap the `configure` command so it's possible to read the entire thing?

I understand there are pagers that let you page sideways, but I would rather not resort to using them.

Comment: Are you sure that `configure` command doesn't simply end with `-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0`?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% positive. I could make the terminal window smaller and less of the command would be visible.

Comment: While annoying, you can inspect the logs, which will probably give you the answer you seek. The output issue may be a Ruby or Homebrew issue; I'd search and, if wanted, file an issue on the [Homebrew issue tracker](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues).

Comment: Logs can be found in [~/Library/Logs/Homebrew](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83827/where-does-homebrew-log).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to format the width to 72 columns:

```
brew install XYZ | fmt -w 72
```

**Sample Output**

```
brew install imagemagick --without-threads --without-libtiff --without-modules | fmt -w 72

==> Using the sandbox ==> Downloading
https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew/mirror/imagemagick-6.9.6-2.tar.xz ==>
./configure --disable-osx-universal-binary
--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.6-2 --disable-silent-rules
--enable-shared --enable-static --without-modules --disable-opencl
--disable-openmp --without-webp --without-openjp2 --without-gslib
--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts --without-fftw
--without-pango --without-threads --without-x --with-freetype=yes ==>
make install   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.6-2: 1,235 files,
22.7M, built in 1 minute 22 seconds
```